# "Expression must have class type" error for a defined class

Tags: c, compiler-errors

If I define a class like this:

```
struct _HNum
{
   char *a;
};
typedef struct _HNum HNum;
```

And then write a function:

```
/*
*Allocates a new HNum with the same value as hnum. It is the caller's
* responsibility to free the returned HNum.
*
* RETURN VALUE:
*   Returns a pointer to the new number, or NULL if the allocation failed.
*/
HNum *HNum_clone(const HNum *hnum)
{
    HNum newNum;
    if(!newNum.a)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(newNum.a, hnum.a);
}
```

The compiler gives the "expression must have class type" error on the "hnum" 
in the line `strcpy(newNum.a, hnum.a);`. What is the problem here?

Comment: is there any reason you don't abbreviate that to: `typedef struct _HNum {...} HNum;`? Also, why do you use a differrent name for the typedef name and the struct tag?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `hnum` is a pointer. Therefore, you need to dereference it - either explicitly with an asterisk, or by using the `->` operator instead of a dot `.`:

```
strcpy(newNum.a, hnum->a);
```

Note: you need to add memory allocation and a `return` statement, otherwise your program has undefined behavior:

```
HNum *HNum_clone(const HNum *hnum)
{
    if(!hnum)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    HNum *newNum = malloc(sizeof(HNum));
    if (hnum->a) {
        newNum->a = malloc(strlen(hnum->a)+1);
        strcpy(newNum->a, hnum->a);
    }
    else
    {
        newNum->a = NULL;
    }
    return newNum;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks it worked, and as for the return value, I know, just didn't finish writing it since the error popped up.

Comment: Perhaps suggest using `strdup()`, and if neccessary defining it himself?

Comment: @Deduplicator Although `strdup` is almost certainly going to be there, it's not part of C99 standard set of string functions. That's why I stay with `malloc`.

Comment: `if(!newNum.a)`? do you mean `if(!hnum->a)`?

Comment: @AlterMann Yes, you are right. There should be two checks, too.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: There's a reason I included "if neccessary defining it himself"...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight When I try to use the code you suggested, in the line
HNum *newNum = malloc(sizeof(HNum)); it says "a value of type "void*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "HNum*".

Comment: @AGPrometheus This happens if you compile with a C++, not a C compiler. I saw the C tag, so I did not add a cast. Switching to C compiler (or using C mode of the C++ compiler) will fix this problem. If you must use C++ compiler with this code, add a cast, like this: `HNum *newNum = (HNum*)malloc(sizeof(HNum));`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you. I'm really new to this, just started studying C. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio but working with C, the way I was taught is to create the file with a .c ending. The cast worked though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code alright?

```
typedef struct _HNum 
{
    char *a;
}HNum;


/*
 * Allocates a new HNum and sets its value to 0.
 *
 * RETURN VALUE:
 *   Returns a pointer to the new number, or NULL if the allocation failed.
 */
HNum *HNum_alloc()
{
    HNum *newNum = (HNum*)malloc(sizeof(HNum));
    newNum->a = (char*)malloc(2);
    if(!newNum->a) return NULL;
    newNum->a = "0";
    return newNum;
}


/*
 *Allocates a new HNum with the same value as hnum. It is the caller's
 * responsibility to free the returned HNum.
 *
 * RETURN VALUE:
 *   Returns a pointer to the new number, or NULL if the allocation failed.
 */
HNum *HNum_clone(const HNum *hnum)
{
    if(!hnum)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    HNum *newNum = HNum_alloc();
    if (hnum->a) {
        strcpy(newNum->a, hnum->a);
    }
    else
    {
        newNum->a = NULL;
    }
    return newNum;
}
```